# SharePoint 2013 connect 500 error

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have found code to connect SharePoint 2013 Service Pack 1:

```
string siteUrl = "adress";

NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password");

ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
clientContext.Credentials = credentials;
Web site = clientContext.Web;

clientContext.Load(site);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

Console.WriteLine("Site information: \n\n");
Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", site.Title);
Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", site.Id);
Console.WriteLine("Language: {0}", site.Language);
Console.WriteLine("UI Version: {0}", site.UIVersion);
Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", site.Description);
Console.WriteLine("Created: {0}", site.Created);

Console.ReadLine();
```

But at the line:

```
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I get:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

Website works well, pass are ok, I have no (at least can't see) problems with IIS, so why I get this exception?

Comment: Does the exception contains an inner exception? As the code you showed, it should be fine. The error should be in the server.

Comment: Can't see anny inner exception, I can add that this SharePoint is on ouer server, it;s littne slow, is this exception can ocure at timeout?

Comment: if time out, you'll get a time out exception

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, /deafult.aspx can't be in adress.